# Online domain or link filter?

Tags: asp.net, blacklist, abuse

I plan to do a tinyurl like site. The problem is i dont want domains to hide behind me if they are up to no good. An example site is http://www.noob.com/. Firefox+google reports it as a attack site. If i can get an automatically updating blacklist for these domains (or links but i prefer domains) then great. Blocking adult sites is good too.

What can i do to prevent abuse of my service?

Answer (score 1):

Google provides [an API for their attack site detection](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/).

Answer (score 0):

You could lean on Google's malware report. They might (probably) have a web service for this, but for starters you could parse the response. Compare for example the [Google Safe Browsing report for noob.com](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://www.noob.com/&client=googlechrome&hl=en-GB) with the same for [ServerFault](http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=https://serverfault.com/&client=googlechrome&hl=en-GB).

Hope that helps.

Comment: @ceejayoz has a better approach. The API is a far better method, quicker, official, and probably supported and less likely to change without notice.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Google's malware detection, check submitted URLs against a couple of URIBLs to weed out spam.